# How to set properties of ControlTemplate's children?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `ControlTemplate` control, it's `x:Name="MyControlTemplate"`. It contains `ListBox` it's `x:Name="MyListBox"`.

Then in my `XAML` code I have:

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}" x:Name="MyContentControl"/>
```

I need to assign `ItemsSource` property to `MyListBox`in `C#`code of `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You would usually bind ItemsSource to a property in your view model.

Comment: Show us your controltemplate - MyControlTemplate

Comment: Are you just having trouble reaching the datacontext to hit your collection for the ItemSource of your nested ListBox? If so it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the list box then just set the property.

```
ListBox listBox = (ListBox) MyContentControl.Template.FindName("MyListBox", MyContentControl);
listBox.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
```